# npm install tries to access wrong host and fails

Tags: windows, npm

I am failing to do `npm install`:

```
λ npm install -g pageres-cli
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://calculon:4873/pageres-cli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.10.99:4873
```

`calculon` is just a name of another computer in my LAN and it is turned off. No relation with it and current computer should exist.

Where to fix?

Comment: Check the content of `$home/.npmrc` file (or if you have a `.npmrc` in your local project check also this file) if there is a registry entry pointing to that machine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have `calculon` defined as a registry in `npm`, you can set default `npm` registry executing this command:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

you can see your registries defined with the following command:

```
npm config get registry
```